# Model Bind List of Enum Flags

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding, enum-flags

I have a grid of Enum Flags in which each record is a row of checkboxes to determine that record's flag values.  This is a list of notifications that the system offers and the user can pick (for each one) how they want them delivered:

```
[Flag]
public enum NotificationDeliveryType
{
  InSystem = 1,
  Email = 2,
  Text = 4
}
```

I found this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194333/mvc-2-passing-enum-to-checkboxfor) but he's getting back a single flag value and he's binding it in the controller like this (with a days of the week concept):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyPostedPage(MyModel model)
{
  //I moved the logic for setting this into a helper 
  //because this could be re-used elsewhere.
  model.WeekDays = Enum<DayOfWeek>.ParseToEnumFlag(Request.Form, "WeekDays[]");
  ...
}
```

I can't find anywhere that the MVC 3 model binder can handle flags. Thanks!

Answer (score 74, accepted):

In general I avoid using enums when designing my view models because they don't play with ASP.NET MVC's helpers and out of the box model binder. They are perfectly fine in your domain models but for view models you could use other types. So I leave my mapping layer which is responsible to convert back and forth between my domain models and view models to worry about those conversions.

This being said, if for some reason you decide to use enums in this situation you could roll a custom model binder:

```
public class NotificationDeliveryTypeModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (value != null )
        {
            var rawValues = value.RawValue as string[];
            if (rawValues != null)
            {
                NotificationDeliveryType result;
                if (Enum.TryParse<NotificationDeliveryType>(string.Join(",", rawValues), out result))
                {
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

which will be registered in Application_Start:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(
    typeof(NotificationDeliveryType), 
    new NotificationDeliveryTypeModelBinder()
);
```

So far so good. Now the standard stuff:

View model:

```
[Flags]
public enum NotificationDeliveryType
{
    InSystem = 1,
    Email = 2,
    Text = 4
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<NotificationDeliveryType> Notifications { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            Notifications = new[]
            {
                NotificationDeliveryType.Email,
                NotificationDeliveryType.InSystem | NotificationDeliveryType.Text
            }
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View (`~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`):

```
@model MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Notification</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Notifications)
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

custom editor template for the `NotificationDeliveryType` (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/NotificationDeliveryType.cshtml`):

```
@model NotificationDeliveryType

<tr>
    <td>
        @foreach (NotificationDeliveryType item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(NotificationDeliveryType)))
        {
            <label for="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(item.ToString())">@item</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(item.ToString())" name="@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(""))" value="@item" @Html.Raw((Model & item) == item ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "") />
        }
    </td>
</tr>
```

It's obvious that a software developer (me in this case) writing such code in an editor template shouldn't be very proud of his work. I mean look t it! Even I that wrote this Razor template like 5 minutes ago can no longer understand what it does.

So we refactor this spaghetti code in a reusable custom HTML helper:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString CheckBoxesForEnumModel<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper)
    {
        if (!typeof(TModel).IsEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("this helper can only be used with enums");
        }
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (Enum item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TModel)))
        {
            var ti = htmlHelper.ViewData.TemplateInfo;
            var id = ti.GetFullHtmlFieldId(item.ToString());
            var name = ti.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty);
            var label = new TagBuilder("label");
            label.Attributes["for"] = id;
            label.SetInnerText(item.ToString());
            sb.AppendLine(label.ToString());

            var checkbox = new TagBuilder("input");
            checkbox.Attributes["id"] = id;
            checkbox.Attributes["name"] = name;
            checkbox.Attributes["type"] = "checkbox";
            checkbox.Attributes["value"] = item.ToString();
            var model = htmlHelper.ViewData.Model as Enum;
            if (model.HasFlag(item))
            {
                checkbox.Attributes["checked"] = "checked";
            }
            sb.AppendLine(checkbox.ToString());
        }

        return new HtmlString(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

and we clean the mess in our editor template:

```
@model NotificationDeliveryType
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.CheckBoxesForEnumModel()
    </td>
</tr>
```

which yields the table:

[image]

Now obviously it would have been nice if we could provide friendlier labels for those checkboxes. Like for example:

```
[Flags]
public enum NotificationDeliveryType
{
    [Display(Name = "in da system")]
    InSystem = 1,

    [Display(Name = "@")]
    Email = 2,

    [Display(Name = "txt")]
    Text = 4
}
```

All we have to do is adapt the HTML helper we wrote earlier:

```
var field = item.GetType().GetField(item.ToString());
var display = field
    .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), true)
    .FirstOrDefault() as DisplayAttribute;
if (display != null)
{
    label.SetInnerText(display.Name);
}
else
{
    label.SetInnerText(item.ToString());
}
```

which gives us a better result:

[image]

Comment: Was there a specific reason a custom ModelBinder was needed? To date I haven't had an issue with a ViewModel accepting a nullable enum or a List of enum and parsing it correctly.

Comment: @Splash-X, it's a flagged enum (one marked with the `[Flags]`) attribute. So you need to be able to perform bitwise operations with it. I am not sure that the default model binder can handle this. Anyways, I don't use enums in my view models.

Comment: Wow... Thanks! This is perfect! To your point about using enums, I agree... This was just a situation that was classical flags and was sure I was missing something with the default model binder...

Comment: Is it possible to have an enum editor set accompanied by a hidden field that keeps the integer value of the enum flags, then use a generator to generate js/jq handlers for each of the checkboxes to modify the value in that hidden field, so when the form is posted back that enum field will be set properly with the new field?

Comment: as I call NotificationDeliveryType.cshtml in view? @Html.Partial("@Html.Partial("DiaDaSemana", Model.diaDaSemana)", Model.Notifications)

Comment: This is quite possibly the best, most helpful answer I've ever found on SO. Still applicable in my solution in 2017! Thanks @DarinDimitrov !

Answer (score 15):

Darin's code was great but I encountered some trouble using it with MVC4.

In the HtmlHelper extension to create the boxes, I kept getting run-time errors that the model was not an enum (specifically, saying System.Object).  I reworked the code to take a Lambda expression and cleaned up this issue using the ModelMetadata class:

```
public static IHtmlString CheckBoxesForEnumFlagsFor<TModel, TEnum>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TEnum>> expression)
{
    ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
    Type enumModelType = metadata.ModelType;

    // Check to make sure this is an enum.
    if (!enumModelType.IsEnum)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("This helper can only be used with enums. Type used was: " + enumModelType.FullName.ToString() + ".");
    }

    // Create string for Element.
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (Enum item in Enum.GetValues(enumModelType))
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(item) != 0)
        {
            var ti = htmlHelper.ViewData.TemplateInfo;
            var id = ti.GetFullHtmlFieldId(item.ToString());
            var name = ti.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty);
            var label = new TagBuilder("label");
            label.Attributes["for"] = id;
            var field = item.GetType().GetField(item.ToString());

            // Add checkbox.
            var checkbox = new TagBuilder("input");
            checkbox.Attributes["id"] = id;
            checkbox.Attributes["name"] = name;
            checkbox.Attributes["type"] = "checkbox";
            checkbox.Attributes["value"] = item.ToString();
            var model = htmlHelper.ViewData.Model as Enum;
            if (model.HasFlag(item))
            {
                checkbox.Attributes["checked"] = "checked";
            }
            sb.AppendLine(checkbox.ToString());

            // Check to see if DisplayName attribute has been set for item.
            var displayName = field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), true)
                .FirstOrDefault() as DisplayNameAttribute;
            if (displayName != null)
            {
                // Display name specified.  Use it.
                label.SetInnerText(displayName.DisplayName);
            }
            else
            {
                // Check to see if Display attribute has been set for item.
                var display = field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), true)
                    .FirstOrDefault() as DisplayAttribute;
                if (display != null)
                {
                    label.SetInnerText(display.Name);
                }
                else
                {
                    label.SetInnerText(item.ToString());
                }
            }
            sb.AppendLine(label.ToString());

            // Add line break.
            sb.AppendLine("<br />");
        }                
    }

    return new HtmlString(sb.ToString());
}
```

I also extended the model binder so it works with any generic enum type.

```
public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    // Fetch value to bind.
    var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
    if (value != null)
    {
        // Get type of value.
        Type valueType = bindingContext.ModelType;

        var rawValues = value.RawValue as string[];
        if (rawValues != null)
        {
            // Create instance of result object.
            var result = (Enum)Activator.CreateInstance(valueType);

            try
            {
                // Parse.
                result = (Enum)Enum.Parse(valueType, string.Join(",", rawValues));
                return result;
            }
            catch
            {
                return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
            }
        }
    }
    return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
}
```

You still need to register each enum type in Application_Start but at least this eliminates the need for separate binder classes. You can register it using:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(MyEnumType), new EnumFlagsModelBinder());
```

I posted my code on Github at https://github.com/Bitmapped/MvcEnumFlags.

Comment: An example would be nice. Especially because the MVC view markup doesn't seem to recognize generic HTML helpers such as your CheckboxesForEnumFlagsFor<>.

Comment: The expression is also not quite clear to me, how would you use such thing? excuse me for not being an MVC power user.

Comment: If you use the helper for enum properties inside a ViewModel class, like `@Html.CheckBoxesForEnumFlagsFor(model => model.MyEnum)` (and I guess the lambda expression is supposed to support this) you must replace `var model = htmlHelper.ViewData.Model as Enum;` by `var model = metadata.Model as Enum;` because `htmlHelper.ViewData.Model` is **not** a enum, it's the ViewModel class.

Comment: Continue... The second thing I needed to change to make it work was replacing `var name = ti.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty);` by `var name = ti.GetFullHtmlFieldName(metadata.PropertyName);`

Comment: Is it possible to have an enum editor set accompanied by a hidden field that keeps the integer value of the enum flags, then use a generator to generate js/jq handlers for each of the checkboxes to modify the value in that hidden field, so when the form is posted back that enum field will be set properly with the new field?

Answer (score 7):

You can try the [MVC Enum Flags](https://mvcenumflags.codeplex.com/) package (available via [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcEnumFlags/)). It automatically skips zero-valued enum choices, which is a nice touch.

*[The following is from the [Documentation](https://mvcenumflags.codeplex.com/documentation) and its comments; see there if this is not binding properly for you]*

After installation, add the following to Global.asax.cs\Application_Start:

`ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(MyEnumType), new EnumFlagsModelBinder());`

Then in the view, put `@using MvcEnumFlags` up top and `@Html.CheckBoxesForEnumFlagsFor(model => model.MyEnumTypeProperty)` for the actual code.

Comment: `MVC Enum Flags` has moved to https://github.com/Bitmapped/MvcEnumFlags

Answer (score 2):

I use approach described in [MVVM Framework](http://mvvmframework.codeplex.com/documentation).

```
 enum ActiveFlags
{
    None = 0,
    Active = 1,
    Inactive = 2,
}

class ActiveFlagInfo : EnumInfo<ActiveFlags>
{
    public ActiveFlagInfo(ActiveFlags value)
        : base(value)
    {
        // here you can localize or set user friendly name of the enum value
        if (value == ActiveFlags.Active)
            this.Name = "Active";
        else if (value == ActiveFlags.Inactive)
            this.Name = "Inactive";
        else if (value == ActiveFlags.None)
            this.Name = "(not set)";
    }
}

   // Usage of ActiveFlagInfo class:
   // you can use collection of ActiveFlagInfo for binding in your own view models
   // also you can use this ActiveFlagInfo as property for your  classes to wrap enum properties

   IEnumerable<ActiveFlagInfo> activeFlags = ActiveFlagInfo.GetEnumInfos(e => 
                    e == ActiveFlags.None ? null : new ActiveFlagInfo(e));
```

Answer (score 1):

Bitmapped, you have asked important questions and i can suggest following solution: you should override BindProperty method of your ModelBinder and next need to override model property value:

```
protected override void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
{
    if (propertyDescriptor.PropertyType.IsEnum && propertyDescriptor.PropertyType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FlagsAttribute), false).Any())
    {
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(propertyDescriptor.Name);
        if (value != null)
        {
            // Get type of value.
            var rawValues = value.RawValue as string[];
            if (rawValues != null)
            {
                // Create instance of result object.
                var result = (Enum)Activator.CreateInstance(propertyDescriptor.PropertyType);
                try
                {
                    // Try parse enum
                    result = (Enum)Enum.Parse(propertyDescriptor.PropertyType, string.Join(",", rawValues));
                    // Override property with flags value
                    propertyDescriptor.SetValue(bindingContext.Model, result);
                    return;
                }
                catch
                {                               
                }
            }
        }
        base.BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor);
    }
    else
        base.BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Darin and bitmapped code, i write the answer, but didn't worked for me, so first i fixed nullable stuff, then still i had bining issue, found out that there's something wrong with the html, so i loos faith on this answer, search for another, that i found something in a forum of my country, that used the same code as here, but with a very little change, so i merge that with my code, and it all went well, my project use nullable, so i don't know how it gonna work on other places, may need a little fix, but i tried to think about nullable and model being the enum itself.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IHtmlString CheckBoxesForEnumFlagsFor<TModel, TEnum>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TEnum>> expression)
    {
        ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        Type enumModelType = metadata.ModelType;

        var isEnum = enumModelType.IsEnum;
        var isNullableEnum = enumModelType.IsGenericType &&
                             enumModelType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (Nullable<>) &&
                             enumModelType.GenericTypeArguments[0].IsEnum;

        // Check to make sure this is an enum.
        if (!isEnum && !isNullableEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("This helper can only be used with enums. Type used was: " + enumModelType.FullName.ToString() + ".");
        }

        // Create string for Element.
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        Type enumType = null;
        if (isEnum)
        {
            enumType = enumModelType;
        }
        else if (isNullableEnum)
        {
            enumType = enumModelType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
        }

        foreach (Enum item in Enum.GetValues(enumType))
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(item) != 0)
            {
                var ti = htmlHelper.ViewData.TemplateInfo;
                var id = ti.GetFullHtmlFieldId(item.ToString());

                //Derive property name for checkbox name
                var body = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
                var propertyName = body.Member.Name;
                var name = ti.GetFullHtmlFieldName(propertyName);

                //Get currently select values from the ViewData model
                //TEnum selectedValues = expression.Compile().Invoke(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model);

                var label = new TagBuilder("label");
                label.Attributes["for"] = id;
                label.Attributes["style"] = "display: inline-block;";
                var field = item.GetType().GetField(item.ToString());

                // Add checkbox.
                var checkbox = new TagBuilder("input");
                checkbox.Attributes["id"] = id;
                checkbox.Attributes["name"] = name;
                checkbox.Attributes["type"] = "checkbox";
                checkbox.Attributes["value"] = item.ToString();

                var model = (metadata.Model as Enum);

                //var model = htmlHelper.ViewData.Model as Enum; //Old Code
                if (model != null && model.HasFlag(item))
                {
                    checkbox.Attributes["checked"] = "checked";
                }
                sb.AppendLine(checkbox.ToString());

                // Check to see if DisplayName attribute has been set for item.
                var displayName = field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), true)
                    .FirstOrDefault() as DisplayNameAttribute;
                if (displayName != null)
                {
                    // Display name specified.  Use it.
                    label.SetInnerText(displayName.DisplayName);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Check to see if Display attribute has been set for item.
                    var display = field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), true)
                        .FirstOrDefault() as DisplayAttribute;
                    if (display != null)
                    {
                        label.SetInnerText(display.Name);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        label.SetInnerText(item.ToString());
                    }
                }
                sb.AppendLine(label.ToString());

                // Add line break.
                sb.AppendLine("<br />");
            }
        }

        return new HtmlString(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

```
public class FlagEnumerationModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("bindingContext");

        if (bindingContext.ValueProvider.ContainsPrefix(bindingContext.ModelName))
        {
            var values = GetValue<string[]>(bindingContext, bindingContext.ModelName);

            if (values.Length > 1 && (bindingContext.ModelType.IsEnum && bindingContext.ModelType.IsDefined(typeof(FlagsAttribute), false)))
            {
                long byteValue = 0;
                foreach (var value in values.Where(v => Enum.IsDefined(bindingContext.ModelType, v)))
                {
                    byteValue |= (int)Enum.Parse(bindingContext.ModelType, value);
                }

                return Enum.Parse(bindingContext.ModelType, byteValue.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
            }
        }

        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }

    private static T GetValue<T>(ModelBindingContext bindingContext, string key)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ValueProvider.ContainsPrefix(key))
        {
            ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key);
            if (valueResult != null)
            {
                bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(key, valueResult);
                return (T)valueResult.ConvertTo(typeof(T));
            }
        }
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(
            typeof (SellTypes),
            new FlagEnumerationModelBinder()
            );
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(
            typeof(SellTypes?),
            new FlagEnumerationModelBinder()
            );
```