# How to store multiple checkbox values in model and render them in view and controller in mvc4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using ASP.NET MVC5 in my application.
I want to show languages known by an employee using check boxes in my view(check boxes with same name). For this how to write my model, pass them from the controller and display them in the view?

I have those vales stored in an Enum

```
public enum Language {
    English=1,
    Telugu=2,
    Hindi=3,
    Spanish=4
}
```

It is ok if I have to store them in a table in DB.

Comment: Using checkboxes with the enum you have shown makes no sense. Do you want to be able to select multiple languages, in which case your enum would need to be marked with the `[Flags]` attribute and the values would need to be 1, 2, 4, 8 (not 1, 2, 3, 4) and the values would be stored as a comma separated string

Answer (score 1):

You can use the  `CheckBoxListFor` helper:

```
 @Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.SelectedOptions, Model.AllOptions)
```

And your model would look like this:

```
public class MyModel {

    // This property contains the available options
    public SelectList AllOptions { get; set; }

    // This property contains the selected options
    public IEnumerable<string> SelectedOptions { get; set; }

    public MyModel() {
        AllOptions = new SelectList(
            new[] { "Option1", "Option2", "Option3" });

        SelectedOptions = new[] { "Option1" };
    }
}
```

In controller you just simply pass your model to the View:

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("Index")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
     var model = new MyModel();
     return View(model);
}
```

You can change the AllOptions and SelectedOptions properties as you want (just remove the code from the constructor of MyModel and place it in your controller class).

For more details check this out, there is a note about how to work with Enum: [CheckBoxList for Enum types MVC Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087615/checkboxlist-for-enum-types-mvc-razor).

Comment: Thanks. Can you add controller part also?

Comment: Also , can you show an example with an Enum type as you have mentioned only strings where I have values and names?

Comment: I used it, thanks. So, if I have radio buttons like this I should do it manually without this type of extension?

Comment: For working with Enum you can use an extention that converts Enum to the SelectedList. I've just created a simple example to show how it should work with strings as it doesn't need any additional manipulations. You can try to implement the solution mentioned there in the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18089259/3731444) and apply it to work with CheckBoxListFor method instead of DropdownFor.