# Render enum as group of inline Bootstrap checkboxes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

Bootstrap can show a group of [inline checkboxes like this](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls):

```
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"> 1
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="option2"> 2
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="option3"> 3
</label>
```

Now suppose that these checkboxes must come from an enum in my viewmodel. So for example I have `HolidayModel.RoomPrefs` which is an enum like this:

```
[Flags]
enum ReservationPreferences {
  Room = 2,
  Breakfast = 4,
  Lunch = 8,
  Dinner = 16
}
```

I want to render this enum as a group of inline checkboxes (i.e. the markup above).

I can do so manually, but I rather use a helper or editor template, or something else generic, because the `HolidayModel` viewmodel has other enums and so I want to reuse the code.

Does Razor have something out of the box to support this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Model Bind List of Enum Flags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264927/model-bind-list-of-enum-flags) (not with Bootstrap checkboxes but pretty easy to adapt)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Wow, interesting but very complicated. Not for Bootstrap as you said. I wonder if there is an easier/better way, as that answer was written many versions ago (of MVC). Also the model binder has knowledge of the concrete model, so it's not exactly generic- was probably the best solution at the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time, MVC has no "out-of-the-box" way to do this. You need to use a combination of custom model binding, and/or editor templates and/or something else.

I've removed enums from my viewmodel and replaced with a series of ugly `bool`s. Does the job.